# png hack for IE6 - best method?

Tags: css

I haven't used a png hack for IE6 for ages. Last time I used one I used this:

http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/

because it supports background-repeat/position on a transparent png set as a background in css.

Is there anything around that has become industry standard that I've missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a "standard" on this one, just use whichever plugin/alternative/maybe hack works for IE6 users.  As long as the performance is good for your target audience and there are no other issues, you're all set.

Personally the sites we're on are also running jQuery, so [this is what I used](http://jquery.andreaseberhard.de/pngFix/), if that helps at all...no issues that I can recall.

---

I think those interested in standardizing things have left IE6 whenever possible, and those stuck with it (corporate environments, *mostly*) are busy trying to find out why life hates them :)

Comment: In other words: IE6 is substandard, forget about it :P

Comment: @BoltClock - *If* you're in a position that you can, yes, run far, far away :)  I realize not everyone is, luckily where I'm at we're fortunate enough to choose what we support.  I really do hate it for all the web devs stuck with it, it's suck a black hole of man hours to fix things *just* for IE6...

Comment: Right thanks. I'll just go with what I've got then.

Unfortunately the client we work for are usually big corporates - and you might not be surprised to find that a signicant proportion of those companies still run IE6. So although the audience we're marketing to may all be using modern browsers the people who are paying are using IE6 so everything needs to be perfect.

I do find most of the time if you're coding corectly then everything should be find in IE6. All I seem to need to do is add display inline for floated elements that have the double margin bug.

Comment: @elduderino - I think you're in a good a position as you can be then...I'm really hoping Windows 7 SP1 will bring lots of upgrades and corporations leaving IE6 so we can move on and really take advantage of later standards...the reason I'm holding out hope is that the Win 7 upgrade means skipping IE7 right to IE8 so we can get a lot more out of the same markup, too much of a dream there?

Comment: Nah, if you *really* want to dream, at least dream for IE9 on all new machines, so that CSS3 and HTML5 support will finally become acceptable standards, instead of icing on the cake

Answer (score 1):

We gave up to use PNG fixes for backgrounds, it slows IE6 a lot and really buggy. So we use separate graphics and CSS for IE6 (simplified or flatten with transparency layers) and link this special CSS using IE conditional comments.

All users starting IE7 will get page with true transparency, IE6 users will get page with simplified graphics, but without any nasty hacks.

Answer (score 1):

I've started using the [Unit PNG Fix](http://labs.unitinteractive.com/unitpngfix.php) lately.  As Nick said, there isn't a standard here, so use whatever works well with your project.

The reason I like Unit PNG is because it allows for opacity animations on transparent .pngs. Ordinarily this creates a horrible black outline around the .png during the animation.  To get it working all you have to do is nest your .png and then animate the opacity on the parent element:

```
<div id="toAnimate">
   <img src="awesome-transparent.png" alt=""/>
</div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$('#toAnimate').animate({opacity: 0});
```